# How to obtain the number of CPUs/cores in Linux from the command line?

Tags: linux, bash, cpu, cpu-cores

I have this script, but I do not know how to get the last element in the printout:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | awk '/^processor/{print $3}'
```

The last element should be the number of CPUs, minus 1.

Comment: You don't need to `cat` before `awk`, anyway: just `awk '<script>' /proc/cpuinfo`, like that: `awk '/^processor/{n+=1}END{print n}' /proc/cpuinfo`. And you get in without "minus one".

Comment: To answer the question directly, pipe that to `tail -n 1` which takes the last line and prints it.

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/564494/5132 .

Comment: You may need `your codes | tail -n 1` as @FábioSantos said, or you can `lscpu` to find something you need ? But if I were you, I'll choose `nproc --all` then minus one.

Answer (score 800, accepted):

```
grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo
```

will count the number of lines starting with "processor" in `/proc/cpuinfo`

For systems with hyper-threading, you can use

```
grep ^cpu\\scores /proc/cpuinfo | uniq |  awk '{print $4}'
```

which should return (for example) `8` (whereas the command above would return `16`)

Comment: Note that both of these will end up counting twice as many cores as actually exist if you're on a system with hyperthreading (e.g, P4, or Core i7).

Comment: @duskwuff: which is precisely what you want in most cases.

Comment: `grep -c '^processor' /proc/cpuinfo` on zsh.

Comment: Will also fail on systems where CPU numbering is not necessarily sequential/contiguous...

Comment: `cat /proc/cpuinfo | awk '/^processor/{print $3}' | tail -1` also will return the wrong number if the CPU numbers are 0-based.

Comment: The first line return 1 Core less then existing. Better cat /proc/cpuinfo | awk '/^processor/{print $3}'| wc -l

Comment: The first line does not work.  The second line is better.  Isn't there a tool to query the actual processor itself and not grep some text file?

Comment: grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo worked for me on RHEL 7.2

Comment: Those two answer give answers that differ  by one for me.

Comment: Just do `grep '^processor' /proc/cpuinfo | wc -l` which will give a count of the number of rows starting with "processor", rather than relying on the 0-based numbering system

Alternatively `grep -c '^processor' /proc/cpuinfo` gives the same result in one command.

Comment: The first one tells me the number of threads. The second one tells me the number of cores per CPU. Neither of these are correct.

Comment: I believe https://stackoverflow.com/a/47435156/1593842 is the correct answer, when the system has lscpu, and https://stackoverflow.com/a/21241550/1593842 is the correct answer when it doesn't. `nproc` is cool, but unlike what Frank Kusters said, it is precisely not the thing I want to know in most cases.

Answer (score 818):

Processing the contents of `/proc/cpuinfo` is needlessly baroque. Use [**nproc**](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/nproc-invocation.html) which is part of coreutils, so it should be available on most Linux installs.

Command `nproc` prints the number of processing units available to the current process, which may be less than the number of online processors.

To find the number of all installed cores/processors use `nproc --all`

On my 8-core machine:

```
$ nproc --all
8
```

Comment: does it distinguish between virtual core and physical core?

Comment: Not that I see. `nproc` reports "2" on my VM which has two virtual cores, and "8" on my real machine which has 8.

Comment: This doesn't work with hyperthreading if I need the number of physical cores. Returns 8 on my quad core i7 box.

Comment: @pratnala - [teambob's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18051445/877069) purports to give you the number of physical cores.

Comment: On my old ubuntu (10.10) nproc is not available. It must be a new-ish addition.

Comment: @pratnala: Actually it does work as expected, `whatis nproc` says _print the number of processing units available_, which is 2 per physical core if hyperthreading is available.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, `nproc` is not a part of boot2docker

Comment: This works for me on Debian and appears to query the processor instead of grep-ing a text file.

Comment: That means you need to install the package which provides nproc.

Comment: In my case it works well without the --all flag

Comment: yes, in LXC just `nproc` shows correct number of cores (assigned to the container), while `nproc --all` shows all cores of the host.

Comment: So are these `nproc`'s cores physical or logical? P.S. Copypasting the man should be prohibited. It's useless.

Comment: For what its worth this works on alpine 3.16 `make all -j\`nproc --all\`; # use all the cores`  .... from `nproc --help` Print the number of processing units available to the current process may be less than the number of online processors
 `nproc  --all`      print the number of installed processors
 `nproc --ignore=N`  if possible, exclude N processing units

Answer (score 319):

The most portable solution I have found is the `getconf` command:

```
getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN
```

This works on both Linux and Mac OS X. Another benefit of this over some of the other approaches is that getconf has been around for a long time. Some of the older Linux machines I have to do development on don't have the `nproc` or `lscpu` commands available, but they have `getconf`.

<sup>Editor's note: While [the `getconf` *utility* is POSIX-mandated](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/getconf.html), the specific `_NPROCESSORS_ONLN` and `_NPROCESSORS_CONF` *values* are not. 
That said, as stated, they work on Linux platforms as well as on macOS; on FreeBSD/PC-BSD, you must omit the leading `_`.</sup>

Comment: This worked for me on Red Hat Entreprise Linux 5.4, Centos 6.5 & 7 and Mac OSX 10.9 (Mavericks). It seems this it the most portable, as lscpu is not installed by default on these systems. Thanks!

Comment: So portable it's in POSIX :)
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/getconf.html

Comment: I like this one. It works on both my CentOS 5.8 and CentOS 7.0.

Comment: @BCran I could not find `_NPROCESSORS_ONLN` in POSIX. Can you link to it?

Comment: @CiroSantilli六四事件法轮功纳米比亚威视 From https://github.com/gstrauss/plasma/blob/master/plasma_sysconf.c it looks like I was wrong: it's only optional.
"sysconf _SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN and _SC_NPROCESSORS_CONF are not required by standards, but are provided on numerous unix platforms and documented as optional by Open Group."

Comment: This one works for me on both RHEL and OS X El Capitan.

Comment: I am using the following command and it doesn't provide required result.
/bin/sh -c getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN
What is the reason? I am trying to run a process and get result by redirecting its output.

Comment: @HaseebJadoon, you missed enclosing the getconf command in quotes `/bin/sh -c 'getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN'`. Though you asked a long time ago, just wanted to share my suggestion if it is helpful for you or someone else.

Comment: Works on Cygwin too.

Comment: This reports `4` on my **2-core** hyperthreaded i5-3230M…

Comment: It doesn't give you the number of "physical cores" of hyper-threaded CPUs. Though It can be useful with prehistoric hardware or systems with hyper-threading turned off.

Comment: This even works exactly if we offline CPUs and find only online CPUs. :)

Answer (score 141):

Preface:

- The **problem with the `/proc/cpuinfo`-based answers** is that they parse information that was meant for *human* consumption and thus **lacks a stable format designed for machine parsing**: the output format can differ across platforms and runtime conditions; **using `lscpu -p` on Linux (and `sysctl` on macOS) bypasses that problem**.
- `getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN` / `getconf NPROCESSORS_ONLN` doesn't distinguish between *logical* and *physical* CPUs.

---

Here's a `sh` (POSIX-compliant) snippet that works on **Linux and macOS** for determining the **number of - online - *logical* or *physical* CPUs**; see the comments for details.

Uses `lscpu` for Linux, and `sysctl` for macOS.

**Terminology note**: *CPU* refers to the smallest processing unit as seen by the OS. Non-hyper-threading cores each correspond to 1 CPU, whereas hyper-threading cores contain more  than 1 (typically: 2) - logical - CPU.
Linux uses the following taxonomy<sup>[1]</sup>, starting with the smallest unit:
*CPU* < *core* < *socket* < *book* < *node*
with each level comprising 1 or more instances of the next lower level.

```
#!/bin/sh

# macOS:           Use `sysctl -n hw.*cpu_max`, which returns the values of 
#                  interest directly.
#                  CAVEAT: Using the "_max" key suffixes means that the *maximum*
#                          available number of CPUs is reported, whereas the
#                          current power-management mode could make *fewer* CPUs 
#                          available; dropping the "_max" suffix would report the
#                          number of *currently* available ones; see [1] below.
#
# Linux:           Parse output from `lscpu -p`, where each output line represents
#                  a distinct (logical) CPU.
#                  Note: Newer versions of `lscpu` support more flexible output
#                        formats, but we stick with the parseable legacy format 
#                        generated by `-p` to support older distros, too.
#                        `-p` reports *online* CPUs only - i.e., on hot-pluggable 
#                        systems, currently disabled (offline) CPUs are NOT
#                        reported.

# Number of LOGICAL CPUs (includes those reported by hyper-threading cores)
  # Linux: Simply count the number of (non-comment) output lines from `lscpu -p`, 
  # which tells us the number of *logical* CPUs.
logicalCpuCount=$([ $(uname) = 'Darwin' ] && 
                       sysctl -n hw.logicalcpu_max || 
                       lscpu -p | egrep -v '^#' | wc -l)

# Number of PHYSICAL CPUs (cores).
  # Linux: The 2nd column contains the core ID, with each core ID having 1 or
  #        - in the case of hyperthreading - more logical CPUs.
  #        Counting the *unique* cores across lines tells us the
  #        number of *physical* CPUs (cores).
physicalCpuCount=$([ $(uname) = 'Darwin' ] && 
                       sysctl -n hw.physicalcpu_max ||
                       lscpu -p | egrep -v '^#' | sort -u -t, -k 2,4 | wc -l)

# Print the values.
cat <<EOF
# of logical CPUs:  $logicalCpuCount
# of physical CPUS: $physicalCpuCount
EOF
```

[1] [macOS `sysctl (3)` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/sysctlbyname.3.html)

Note that BSD-derived systems other than macOS - e.g., FreeBSD - only support the `hw.ncpu` key for `sysctl`, which are deprecated on macOS; I'm unclear on which of the new keys `hw.npu` corresponds to: `hw.(logical|physical)cpu_[max]`.

<sup>Tip of the hat to @teambob for helping to correct the physical-CPU-count `lscpu` command.</sup>

**Caveat**: `lscpu -p` output does NOT include a "book" column (the `man` page mentions "books" as an entity between socket and node in the taxonomic hierarchy). If "books" are in play on a given Linux system (*does anybody know when and how?*), the physical-CPU-count command may *under*-report (this is based on the assumption that `lscpu` reports IDs that are non-unique *across higher-level entities*; e.g.: 2 different cores from 2 different sockets could have the same ID).

---

If you **save the code above as, say, shell script `cpus`**, make it executable with `chmod +x cpus` and place it in folder in your `$PATH`, you'll see output such as the following:

```
$ cpus
logical  4
physical 4
```

---

<sup>[1] [Xaekai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/457057/xaekai) sheds light on what a *book* is: "a *book* is a module that houses a circuit board with CPU sockets, RAM sockets, IO connections along the edge, and a hook for cooling system integration. They are used in IBM mainframes. Further info: http://ewh.ieee.org/soc/cpmt/presentations/cpmt0810a.pdf"</sup>

Comment: Yes sorry you are correct about the sort command. I can't find any information about books beyond the lscpu manual. I think it is related to NUMA http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_memory_access

Comment: I think most solutions here ignore multi-socket machines, unlike this one. Thanks!

Comment: In terms of linux, there are many contexts where lscpu isn't available, such as installer images. I like it.. wish it were ubiquitous.

Answer (score 49):

`lscpu` gathers CPU architecture information form /proc/cpuinfon in human-read-able format:

```
# lscpu


Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                8
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-7
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    4
CPU socket(s):         2
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 15
Stepping:              7
CPU MHz:               1866.669
BogoMIPS:              3732.83
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              4096K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-7
```

See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/468766/understanding-output-of-lscpu.

Answer (score 23):

Here's the way I use for counting the number of physical cores that are online on Linux:

```
lscpu --online --parse=Core,Socket | grep --invert-match '^#' | sort --unique | wc --lines
```

or in short:

```
lscpu -b -p=Core,Socket | grep -v '^#' | sort -u | wc -l
```

Example (1 socket):

```
> lscpu
...
CPU(s):                28
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    14
Socket(s):             1
....
> lscpu -b -p=Core,Socket | grep -v '^#' | sort -u | wc -l
14
```

Example (2 sockets):

```
> lscpu
...
CPU(s):                56
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    14
Socket(s):             2
...
> lscpu -b -p=Core,Socket | grep -v '^#' | sort -u | wc -l
28
```

Example (4 sockets):

```
> lscpu
...
CPU(s):                64
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    8
Socket(s):             4
...
> lscpu -b -p=Core,Socket | grep -v '^#' | sort -u | wc -l
32
```

Comment: Works and handles multiple sockets

Comment: This is the best answer.

Comment: This is the only answer working on multi-CPU + hyperthreading setup.

Answer (score 18):

You can also use Python! To get the number of physical cores:

```
$ python -c "import psutil; print(psutil.cpu_count(logical=False))"
4
```

To get the number of hyperthreaded cores:

```
$ python -c "import psutil; print(psutil.cpu_count(logical=True))"
8
```

Comment: With python  2.7.15 these commands do not print anything. In REPL they do.

Comment: @VytenisBivainis Thanks, I fixed my answer!

Comment: So many of the tool mentioned here aren't available on base mac; python is!
Life-saver!

Answer (score 12):

For the total number of physical cores:

```
grep '^core id' /proc/cpuinfo |sort -u|wc -l
```

On multiple-socket machines (or always), multiply the above result by the number of sockets:

```
echo $(($(grep "^physical id" /proc/cpuinfo | awk '{print $4}' | sort -un | tail -1)+1))
```

@mklement0 has quite a nice answer below using lscpu. I have written a more succinct version in the comments

Answer (score 10):

Using getconf is indeed the most portable way, however the variable has different names in BSD and Linux to getconf, so you have to test both, as this gist suggests:
https://gist.github.com/jj1bdx/5746298
(also includes a Solaris fix using ksh)

I personally use:

```
$ getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN 2>/dev/null || getconf NPROCESSORS_ONLN 2>/dev/null || echo 1
```

And if you want this in python you can just use the syscall getconf uses by importing the os module:

```
$ python -c 'import os; print os.sysconf(os.sysconf_names["SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN"]);'
```

As for `nproc`, it's part of GNU Coreutils, so not available in BSD by default. It uses sysconf() as well after some other methods.

Comment: Bonus: it works on macs too

Answer (score 10):

Crossplatform solution for Linux, MacOS, Windows:

```
CORES=$(grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo 2>/dev/null || sysctl -n hw.ncpu || echo "$NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS")
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to do this so it works on linux and OS X, you can do:

```
CORES=$(grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo 2>/dev/null || sysctl -n hw.ncpu)
```

Comment: On mine, this returns the number of hyperthreads.  I'd also need to know the number of physical cores and number of sockets.

Comment: OK - the exact same command with hw.physicalcpu yields the core count.  Not sure yet about the socket count...  There's also a "logical" and "active" cpu count, but I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: Quick update - this doesn't seem so portable.  I tried it on a Linux box, and it seems to just read the /proc directories, which are all different for the Linux system than the Mac - for example, there's no hw subdirectory.  That being said, you can still parse /proc/cpuinfo

Answer (score 6):

You can use one of the following methods to determine the number of **physical** CPU cores.

- Count the number of unique core ids (roughly equivalent to `grep -P '^core id\t' /proc/cpuinfo | sort -u | wc -l`).

  `awk '/^core id\t/ {cores[$NF]++} END {print length(cores)}' /proc/cpuinfo`
- Multiply the number of 'cores per socket' by the number of sockets.

  `lscpu | awk '/^Core\(s\) per socket:/ {cores=$NF}; /^Socket\(s\):/ {sockets=$NF}; END{print cores*sockets}'`
- Count the number of unique logical CPU's as used by the Linux kernel. The `-p` option generates output for easy parsing and is compatible with earlier versions of `lscpu`.

  `lscpu -p | awk -F, '$0 !~ /^#/ {cores[$1]++} END {print length(cores)}'`

---

Just to reiterate what others have said, there are a number of related properties.

To determine the number of processors available:

```
getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN
grep -cP '^processor\t' /proc/cpuinfo
```

To determine the number of processing units available (not necessarily the same as the number of cores). This is hyperthreading-aware.

```
nproc
```

I don't want to go too far down the rabbit-hole, but you can also determine the number of configured processors (as opposed to simply available/online processors) via `getconf _NPROCESSORS_CONF`. To determine total number of CPU's (offline and online) you'd want to parse the output of `lscpu -ap`.

Comment: this is the correct answer if you want physical cores.

Answer (score 6):

It is very simple. Just use this command:

```
lscpu
```

Comment: You'd need to grep the output of this for `CPU(s):`.

Answer (score 6):

The above answers are applicable to most situations, but **if you are in a docker container environment and your container is limited by `CpusetCpus`, then you can't actually get the real cpu cores through the above method**.

In this case, you need do this to get the real cpu cores:

```sh
grep -c 'cpu[0-9]' /proc/stat
```

Comment: Great solution ;-) Can't you get rid of the first `grep` in `| grep cpu | grep -E 'cpu[0-9]+' |`?

Comment: Nit 1: you don't need the `+` (and so also don't need the `-E`). You just need `cpu` to be followed by at least one digit. Nit 2: you don't need `cat`: you can just `grep 'cpu[0-9]' /proc/stat`.

Answer (score 4):

In case anybody was wondering, here is what the Python `psutil.cpu_count(logical=False)` call does on Linux in equivalent shell script:

```sh
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu[0-9]*/topology/core_cpus_list | sort -u | wc -l
```

And here’s a slightly longer version that falls back to the information from the deprecated *thread_siblings_list* file if *core_cpus_list* isn’t available (psutil has this fallback):

```sh
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu[0-9]*/topology/{core_cpus_list,thread_siblings_list} | sort -u | wc -l
```

Comment: In the first command you should use `sort -u` (or `sort | uniq`) instead of `uniq`

Comment: @Fravadona: You're right! Using just `uniq` will work since the list of cores will evaluate in order with hyperthreads generally having been added at the same time, but it might not be guaranteed…!

Comment: There's no guaranty indeed: I got one wrong result while testing the command on a few 4-socket servers; now all's good ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The following should give you the number of "real" cores on both a hyperthreaded and non-hyperthreaded system. At least it worked in all my tests.

```
awk -F: '/^physical/ && !ID[$2] { P++; ID[$2]=1 }; /^cpu cores/ { CORES=$2 };  END { print CORES*P }' /proc/cpuinfo
```

Comment: -1, this returns `0` on a single core with an Opteron 4170 HE, but returns `4` on an eight core box with an Opteron 3280. ...part of me really wishes this one-liner would work!

Answer (score 3):

I also thought `cat /proc/cpuinfo` would give me the correct answer, however I recently saw that my ARM quad core Cortex A53 system only showed a single core. It seems that /proc/cpuinfo only shows the active cores, whereas:

`cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/present`

is a better measure of what's there.  You can also

`cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/online`

to see which cores are online, and

`cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/offline`

to see which cores are offline.  The `online`, `offline`, and `present` sysfs entries return the index of the CPUS, so a return value of `0` just means core 0, whereas a return value of `1-3` means cores 1,2, and 3.

See https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-devices-system-cpu

Answer (score 2):

Not my web page, but this command from http://www.ixbrian.com/blog/?p=64&cm_mc_uid=89402252817914508279022&cm_mc_sid_50200000=1450827902 works nicely for me on centos. It will show actual cpus even when hyperthreading is enabled.

`cat /proc/cpuinfo | egrep "core id|physical id" | tr -d "\n" | sed s/physical/\\nphysical/g | grep -v ^$ | sort | uniq | wc -l`

Comment: +1, longer than the solution with "lscpu -p=Core,Socket" but works directly parsing /proc/cpuinfo, no need for lscpu.

Comment: arrrgh! I did not see this one and wasted a bunch of time trying to come with my own. I had the same idea because `lscpu`is not available on my system, but yours is simpler than mine (https://stackoverflow.com/a/63248763/1593842). Would you mind explaining the `grep -v` part? PS: we could save some cycles by replacing `sort | uniq' with `sort -u`, right?

Answer (score 2):

Most answers in this thread pertain to *logical* cores.

Using BaSH on Ubuntu 18.x, I find this works well to determine **number of physical** CPUs:

```
numcpu="$(lscpu | grep -i 'socket(s)' | awk '{print $(2)}')"
```

It should work on most Linux distros.

Answer (score 1):

Count "core id" per "physical id" method using awk with fall-back on "processor" count if "core id" are not available (like raspberry)

```
echo $(awk '{ if ($0~/^physical id/) { p=$NF }; if ($0~/^core id/) { cores[p$NF]=p$NF }; if ($0~/processor/) { cpu++ } } END { for (key in cores) { n++ } } END { if (n) {print n} else {print cpu} }' /proc/cpuinfo)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep processor
```

This worked fine.  When I tried the first answer I got 3 CPU's as the output.  I know that I have 4 CPUs on the system so I just did a `grep` for processor and the output looked like this:

```
[root@theservername ~]# cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep processor
processor       : 0
processor       : 1
processor       : 2
processor       : 3
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's okay that you can use Python, then [`numexpr`](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr) module has a function for this:

```
In [5]: import numexpr as ne

In [6]: ne.detect_number_of_cores()
Out[6]: 8
```

also this:

```
In [7]: ne.ncores
Out[7]: 8
```

---

To query this information from the command prompt use:

```
# runs whatever valid Python code given as a string with `-c` option
$ python -c "import numexpr as ne; print(ne.ncores)"
8
```

---

Or simply it is possible to get this info from [`multiprocessing.cpu_count()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process#multiprocessing.cpu_count) function

```
$ python -c "import multiprocessing; print(multiprocessing.cpu_count())"
```

Or even more simply use [`os.cpu_count()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/os.html#os.cpu_count)

```
$ python -c "import os; print(os.cpu_count())"
```

Comment: Is there a way make this work as a command in python? For example I tried python -m numexpr.ncores but that doesn't work.

Comment: @MonsieurBeilto Please have a look at the updated answer!

Comment: The count returned by `cpu_count` is wrong, it doesn't return the number of cores but merely the number of hyperthreads on Intel CPUs

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to count physical cores, this command did it for me.

```
lscpu -e | tail -n +2 | tr -s " " | cut -d " " -f 4 | sort | uniq | wc -w
```

Pretty basic, but seems to count actual physical cores, ignoring the logical count

Comment: That is 6 processes!
   ` awk '/^processor/{x=$3};END{print x}' < /proc/cpuinfo `
just one

Answer (score 1):

Use below query to get core details

```
[oracle@orahost](TESTDB)$ grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo
8
```

Answer (score 1):

[Fravadona's answer is awesome and correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47435156/1593842), but it requires the presence of `lscpu`. Since it is not present on the system where I need the number of physical cores, I tried to come up with one that relies only on `proc/cpuinfo`

`cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep -B2 'core id' | sed 's/siblings.*/'/ | tr -d '[:space:]' | sed 's/--/\n/'g | sort -u | wc -l`

It works perfectly, but unfortunately it isn't as robust as Fravadona's, since it will break if

- the name or order of the fields inside `/proc/cpuinfo` changes
- `grep` replaces the line separator it inserts (currently `--`) by some other string.

BUT, other than that, it works flawlessly :)

Here is a quick explanation of everything that is happening

```
grep -B2 'core id'
```

get only the lines we are interested (i.e "core id" and the 2 preceding lines)

```
sed 's/siblings.*/'/
```

remove the "siblings..." line

```
tr -d '[:space:]'
```

replace spacing chars

```
sed 's/--/\n/'g
```

replace the '--' char, which was inserted by grep, by a line break

```
sort -u
```

group by "physical id,core id"

```
wc -l
```

count the number of lines

Being a total noobie, I was very pleased with myself when this worked. I never thought I would be able to join the required lines together to group by "physical id" and "core id". It is kind of hacky, but works.

If any guru knows a way to simplify this mess, please let me know.

Comment: You can also try [ntninja's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68273982/3387716), it may work for your case ;-)

Answer (score 1):

One more answer among the numerous previous ones. It is possible to use the cgroups when they are available. The [cpuset](https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/cgroup-v1/cpusets.html) sub-system provides the list of actives cpus. This can be listed in the top most cgroup of the hierarchy in */sys/fs/cgroup*. For example:

```
$ cat /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset/cpuset.effective_cpus
0-3
```

Then, a parsing of the latter would be necessary to get the number of active CPUs. The content of this file is a comma separated list of CPU sets.

Here is an example using `tr` to break the list into single expressions and using `sed` to translate the intervals into arithmetic operations passed to `expr`:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

# For test purposes, the CPU sets are passed as parameters
#cpuset=`cat /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset/cpuset.effective_cpus`
cpuset=$1

ncpu=0
for e in `echo $cpuset | tr ',' ' '`
do
  case $e in

    # CPU interval ==> Make an arithmetic operation
    *-*) op=`echo $e | sed -E 's/([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)/\2 - \1 + 1/'`;;

    # Single CPU number
    *) op=1;;

  esac

  ncpu=`expr $ncpu + $op`

done

echo $ncpu
```

Here are some examples of executions with several flavors of CPU sets:

```
$ for cpuset in "0" "0,3" "0-3" "0-3,67" "0-3,67,70-75" "0,1-3,67,70-75"
> do
>   ncpu.sh $cpuset
> done
1
2
4
5
11
11
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering your specific sample code snippet that prints information on available CPU cores e.g.

```bash
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo | awk '/^processor/{print $3}'
```

## Two approaches

### Derive total value based on the highest cpu core id value

Taking an an advantage of the fact that CPU cores have a *sequential number* attached to them and stored under a `processor` field. Because of the fact that the information about each individual CPU core stores in `proc` file is in a list ordered by `processor` field ascending, you can simply grab the last entry of that sequence and observe the numerical value in the `processor` field e.g.

```bash
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo | awk '/^processor/{print $3}' | tail -n 1
```

> NOTE: Since `/proc/cpuinfo` holds a number of entries corresponding to the cpus count, a `processor` field initial value is 0, don't forget to increment the value of the last cpu core by 1.

```bash
$ last_cpu_core_id=$(/proc/cpuinfo | awk '/^processor/{print $3}' | tail -n 1)
$ echo $((last_cpu_core_id + 1))
```

### Count number of lines from the output

This approach contrasts with the first one in that, we are not really concerned about a particular value of cpu core id, we just counting output lines. When it comes to counting, the process normally starts from 1 which simplifies our solution.

#### Using `grep`

```bash
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep processor | wc -l
```

Alternatively, we shouldn't necessarily remember the `processor` field per se, but taking an advantage of the fact that each entry describing individual cpu core details is delimited by a newline e.g.

```bash
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep -v '^\w' | wc -l
```

#### using `awk`

```bash
cat /proc/cpuinfo | awk '($1 == "processor") {count++ } END { print count }'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 dmidecode  | grep -i cpu | grep Version
```

gives me

> Version: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2667 v4 @ 3.20GHz
>
> Version: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2667 v4 @ 3.20GHz

Which is correct socket count - looking up the `E5-2667` tells me each socket has `8 cores`, so multiply and end up with `16 cores` across `2 sockets`.

Where `lscpu` give me `20 CPUs` - which is totally incorrect - not sure why. (same goes for `cat /proc/cpu` - ends up with `20`.

Comment: While that may be technically correct, the code you posted does not yield the number of cores (physical or logical), but instead prints the list of sockets and requires you to manually look up the processors specs. Obviously this isn't even remotely useful for scripted usage, requires root privileges and I just noticed it doesn't even work on my system since *Version: AMD FX-8800P Radeon R7, 12 Compute Cores 4C+8G* does not contain the word CPU…

Answer (score 0):

### Quicker, without fork

This works with almost all [shell](/questions/tagged/shell).

```
ncore=0
while read line ;do
    [ "$line" ] && [ -z "${line%processor*}" ] && ncore=$((ncore+1))
  done </proc/cpuinfo
echo $ncore
4
```

In order to stay compatible with [shell](/questions/tagged/shell), [dash](/questions/tagged/dash),  [busybox](/questions/tagged/busybox) and others, I've used `ncore=$((ncore+1))` instead of `((ncore++))`.

#### [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) version

```
ncore=0
while read -a line ;do
    [ "$line" = "processor" ] && ((ncore++))
  done </proc/cpuinfo
echo $ncore
4
```

Comment: This post is linked to [this answer to String contains in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20460402/1765658)!

Answer (score 0):

Python 3 also provide a few simple ways to get it:

```
$ python3 -c "import os; print(os.cpu_count());"
```

4

```
$ python3 -c "import multiprocessing; print(multiprocessing.cpu_count())"
```

4

Comment: This does return 8 for me when I have 4 cores with 2 threads on each...

Answer (score 0):

Summary:
to get **physical CPUs** do this:

```
grep 'core id' /proc/cpuinfo | sort -u
```

to get **physical** and **logical** CPUs do this:

```
grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo
```

`/proc` << this is the golden source of any info you need about processes and

`/proc/cpuinfo` << is the golden source of any CPU information.

Comment: The physical CPU counting doesn't work with multi-socket computers; for that you need to associate each 'core id' to its 'physical id'.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/^processor/{x=$3};END{print x}' < /proc/cpuinfo
```

Single binary (no chaining), shows you not a count but the processor number of the last core - which would usually be the same.