# What is the appropriate number of Gunicorn workers for each Amazon Instance Type?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, gunicorn, worker, worker-process

I'm currently trying to figure out what the appropriate number of workers is for each Amazon Instance Type. I used to run one Gunicorn worker, however that proved to be quite slow.

Many developers are currently using this formula to gauge how many workers would be suitable:

```
NUM_WORKERS=3  #recommended formula here is 1 + 2 * NUM_CORES
```

The problem I'm having is that Amazon isn't quite clear as to the number of cores each instance is running. For example, an M1 Small Instance has 1 EC2 Compute Unit (1 virtual core with 1 EC2 Compute Unit)

What does that essentially mean? That it has one core? or that it has two cores?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I know this is a old question. But I think I have a better answer to this question. Gunicorn docs suggests that 2n+1 [`gunicorn -w <2n+1> myapp:wsgi`] is a good guess for number of workers (Yes, n = number of cores). I came up with a tiny shell script to apply this formula. All you need to do is this:

```
gunicorn -w $(( 2 * `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'core id' | wc -l` + 1 )) myapp:wsgi
```

Where the command

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'core id' | wc -l
```

will return the total number of actual CPU cores (n). So

```
$(( 2 * `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'core id' | wc -l` + 1 ))
```

equates to 2n+1 formula.

This will apply 2n+1 formula to all the linux-based machines. You dont need to know the number of workers for each type of instance or anything like that.

Reference: http://dhilipsiva.com/2015/10/22/appropriate-number-of-gunicorn-workers.html

Comment: **gunicorn.conf.py** import multiprocessing; workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2 + 1 http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/19.3/configure.html

Comment: @kev so is using a .py instead of a gunicorn.service file advised?

Comment: @Mr-Programs not sure anymore what filetype it is, but it is (still) in the official documentation: https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/19.9.0/configure.html

Comment: Why not simply use `$(( 2 * \`nproc\` + 1 ))` to get the number of processing units available?

Comment: @Faheel, did not know that such a command existed :P

Comment: aws ec2 advertises threads, not the physical cores. ex, a 4-core cpu that supports hyperthreading has 8 cores, which is what aws advertises, you can check it by doing `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'cores'`. with this answer, i am now confused, should i use "(2 * n-cores) + 1" or "(2 * n-threads) + 1"?

Comment: @NaveenReddyMarthala More accurately, each thread is a vCPU core in EC2. i.e number of vCPU cores = number of threads. So they are one and the same as far as EC2 is concerned.

Comment: yes, but do I use one workder per cpu-thread or vCPU or one worker per core(2 threads)?

Comment: @NaveenReddyMarthala My guess is, 2*vCPU + 1; Not entirely sure if its the right thing to do.

Answer (score 22):

Building on [epicbrew's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23569003/143880) work, here's how to launch 2N+1 Gunicorn workers, where N = number of CPU cores:

```
gunicorn --workers=$((2 * $(getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN) + 1)) wsgi:application
```

This works on both Linux and macOS!  More detail on the [John Tells All blog.](http://johntellsall.blogspot.com/2016/07/tip-running-2n1-gunicorn-workers.html)

Answer (score 8):

The [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) `m1.small` instance type definitely has one virtual core only; from a threading/worker perspective you can ignore the *EC2 Compute Unit (ECU)* specification entirely and take the listed number of (virtual) cores on the [Amazon EC2 Instance Types](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) page literally, multiplying by the number of listed CPUs, where applicable (only relevant for cluster instances).

If you want to avoid doing the math and/or have programmatic access to that information, you might want to have a look at the [missingcloud](https://github.com/garnaat/missingcloud) project - the [aws.json](https://github.com/garnaat/missingcloud/blob/master/aws.json) dataset features a cores field within the [instance_types](https://github.com/garnaat/missingcloud/blob/ce837e214ff43742594821b3e5a995e1d99c095b/aws.json#L627) collection, e.g.:

```js
"instance_types" : {
        "m1.small" : {
            "compute_units" : 1,
            "cores" : 1,
            "gpus" : 0,
            "ramMB" : 1700,
            "storageGB" : [10, 160],
            "i/o" : "moderate",
            "ebs_optimized_iopsMbps" : 0,
            "arch" : [32,64]},
        ...
}
```

Comment: why do you advise to not get this info programatically? gunicorn documentation even has it done programmatically

Answer (score 3):

An easy way to see how many cpu's are detected is to run top and press "1" to show the number of cpu's. You will see cpu0, cpu1, cpu2 etc.