# How to detect number of CPU cores in Crystal?

Tags: crystal-lang

How do you detect the number of CPU cores in crystal?

In Go you can do `runtime.NumCPU()` and in Node.js you can do `os.cpus()`. Is there something similar in Crystal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last time I checked (admittedly that was long ago) there was no direct way to do that, but you can get access to this information through the command line. I ended up combining multiple of [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481005/how-to-obtain-the-number-of-cpus-cores-in-linux-from-the-command-line) for redundancy.

```
THREADS = `getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN || nproc --all || grep -c '^processor' /proc/cpuinfo`.to_i
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `System.cpu_count`. This will give you the number of logical cores available. This method was introduced in Crystal `0.23.0`.

Here's the source for it in the tree for Crystal `0.29.0`: https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/blob/fbfe8b62f44eca4596090b7580801bd184f73c7a/src/system.cr#L22