# Getting number of cores for EMR cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, emr

I am using 3 instances of r4.2x large for my slave node in my emr cluster which has 8 cpu .How do i determine the number of cores available in the cluster .I used the following command to determine this :

```
grep cores /proc/cpuinfo
```

It says i have 1 core per cpu .

For spark ETL job is it better to use R series of AWS instance or C series .Also is the above command the right way to determine the cores available for the cluster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of cores in your EMR cluster is simply the sum of the cores per core/task instance multiplied by the cores of the instance type you're using. So in your case it'd be:

```
3 instances * 8 cores (per r4.2xlarge) = 24 cores
```

I assume you're confused by the content of `/proc/cpuinfo`. If you look at it without grepping for cores you'll see multiple processors mentioned. Maybe check out: [How to obtain the number of CPUs/cores in Linux from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481005/how-to-obtain-the-number-of-cpus-cores-in-linux-from-the-command-line)

Keep in mind that this sum of CPUs is not necessarily the number of CPUs working on your tasks, as that also depends on the configuration of Hadoop/Spark.

Regarding the instance types: Which type to choose depends on your workload. If it's a memory heavy workload (like Spark jobs usually are) EC2-instances from the memory-heavy R-families are probably a better choice than instances from the CPU-heavy C-families of instances.

Comment: what is the best way to determine whether spark etl job is cpu or memory heavy .