# How to get number of executors and number of cores in Java spark

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am new to Spark and we are coding in Java now. The problem is that we are trying to figure out the number of executors and number of cores. I googled and saw some articles that mentioning that  the way to do that in Spark as below. But didn't see anything similar in Java (JavaSparkContext doesn't have `getExecutorMemoryStatus` or `getExecutorStorageStatus`). Can anyone help, please?

```
 // for executor numbers
 def currentActiveExecutors(sc: SparkContext): Seq[String] = {
         val allExecutors = sc.getExecutorMemoryStatus.map(_._1)
         val driverHost: String = sc.getConf.get("spark.driver.host")
         allExecutors.filter(! _.split(":")(0).equals(driverHost)).toList
       }

  // for executor core numbers
  int(sc._conf.get('spark.executor.cores'))
```

Comment: [`SparkContext`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html) seems to be available from java api so why cannot you use it?

Comment: Specifically you can obtain `SparkContext` from `JavaSparkContext` by using static method [`JavaSparkContext::toSparkContext`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaSparkContext.html#toSparkContext-org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext-)

Comment: This SO answer will help you - https://stackoverflow.com/a/47405382/4758823

Answer (score 1):

My answer is mostly based on [this SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47405382/4758823).
Recently, `getExecutorStorageStatus` has been removed from `SparkContext`(in the newer version of spark). Hence you can't use `sc. getExecutorStorageStatus`. Instead we can use SparkEnv's `blockManager.master.getStorageStatus.length - 1` (the minus one is for the driver again). The normal way to get to it, via `env` of `SparkContext`. But it is not accessible outside of the `org.apache.spark` package. Therefore, we use an **`encapsulation violation pattern`** as:

```scala
package org.apache.spark.util

import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkEnv}

/**
  * Below objects are not accessible outside of the org.apache.spark.util package.
  * Therefore, we use an encapsulation violation pattern.
  */
object SparkInternalUtils {

  def sparkEnv(sc: SparkContext): SparkEnv = sc.env
  def getThreadUtils: ThreadUtils.type = ThreadUtils

}
```

Now, we can get the instance of `SparkEnv` using `SparkInternalUtils.sparkEnv(sc)`

Define RichSparkContext as below-

```scala
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.util.SparkInternalUtils

import scala.language.implicitConversions


class RichSparkContext(val sc: SparkContext) {

  def executorCount: Int =
    SparkInternalUtils.sparkEnv(sc).blockManager.master.getStorageStatus.length - 1 // one is the driver

  def coresPerExecutor: Int =
    RichSparkContext.coresPerExecutor(sc)

  def coreCount: Int =
    executorCount * coresPerExecutor

  def coreCount(coresPerExecutor: Int): Int =
    executorCount * coresPerExecutor

}


object RichSparkContext {

  trait Enrichment {
    implicit def enrichMetadata(sc: SparkContext): RichSparkContext =
      new RichSparkContext(sc)
  }

  object implicits extends Enrichment

  private var _coresPerExecutor: Int = 0

  def coresPerExecutor(sc: SparkContext): Int =
    synchronized {
      if (_coresPerExecutor == 0)
        sc.range(0, 1).map(_ => java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime.availableProcessors).collect.head
      else _coresPerExecutor
    }

}
```

**`In scala, get the number of executors & and core count`**

```scala
val sc = ... // SparkContext instance
    import RichSparkContext.implicits._
    val executorCount = sc.executorCount
val coresPerExecutor = sc.coresPerExecutor
val totalCoreCount = sc.coreCount
```

**`In java, get the number of executors & and core count`**

```java
 JavaSparkContext javaSparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(spark.sparkContext());
        RichSparkContext richSparkContext = new RichSparkContext(javaSparkContext.sc());
        System.out.println(richSparkContext.coresPerExecutor());
        System.out.println(richSparkContext.coreCount());
        System.out.println(richSparkContext.executorCount());
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, @Someshwar. I am not sure if my spark package version is too old or it should be some other packages, I cannot see the class RichSparkContext. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Tried above answer and found the executor count can be fetched this way:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkEnv
val executorCount = SparkEnv.get.blockManager.master.getStorageStatus.length
```