# Spark Standalone Mode: Is there a way to programmatically get cores/memory information for each worker from Spark's localhost:8080

Tags: java, apache-spark, kubernetes

I need a mechanism to be able to automatically known the current Spark cluster's status in my code in order to decide how many resource should my code request.

I saw this:
[Spark: get number of cluster cores programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47399087/spark-get-number-of-cluster-cores-programmatically)

But:

1. Their answer is wrong, `java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime.availableProcessors` tell you how many cores are there on the Physical machine, however you can start a Spark worker that has # cores of worker < # actual number of cores on the machine. This is even a common practice in Kubernetes.
2. There are no way to extract the memory. Again, you can't call `java.lang.Runtime` because it again only show information regarding to the host. And it is a even more common practice to make the size mismatch since all those issue you get in Java when memory goes bigger than 30GB.

So is there a way that I can pragmatically extract the exact information like they are in localhost:8080?

[image]

I can not move to YARN in the meantime, I know this would solve the problem but it is too complicated.

I know I can parse the result from the URL but that's too complicated.

Some attempts that didn't work:

1. `sparkContext.executorMemory()` this only returns the memory you requested.
2. `sparkContext.defaultParallelism()` this returns you correctly the total number of cores, but not the number of cores on one worker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, if you can assume all your worker are the same - which is a significantly better assumption than all the above ones but can still be wrong some times - you can use `sparkContext.defaultParallelism() / (sparkContext.statusTracker().getExecutorInfos().length - 1)` to get the number of cores.

To get the memory, the easiest way is to hack based on environmental variable:

```
System.getenv("SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY")
```

and just run it remotely on Spark Worker