# Multiple GitLab Runner Docker instances at one host?

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I need to configure GitLab runner to run multiple shared runners in Docker containers at one server (host).

So, I registered two runners with `gitlab-runner register` as shared runners with same tag.

But there is an issue now - only one of them is currently using and all other tasks are waiting in Pending status until the first runner is stopped. So, second runner instance is not using, until first instance will be stopped.

All tasks have same tag.

How to run multiple runners at same server host?

Comment: Could you try increasing the limit/concurrency? Also posting your config.toml here would help.

Comment: Oh, really, I forgot about `concurrent = 1` option in config.toml file. Thank you!

Comment: I would accept the answer provided. Running more than 1 gitlab-runner per node is totally unnecessary as it can run concurrent job. As stated setting concurrent=n ,0 is NOT unlimited, will run n job at the same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default concurrent is 1, so unless you increase it your runner will just use one registration at a time: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-global-section

> limits how many jobs globally can be run concurrently. The most upper limit of jobs using all defined runners. 0 does not mean unlimited

Answer (score 0):

To utilize all your CPU cores set `concurrent` in `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml` (when running as root) or `~/.gitlab-runner/config.toml` (when running as non root) to the number of your CPUs.

You can find the number of CPUs like this: `grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo`.

In my case the `config.toml` says `concurrent = 8`

Citations:

- Gitlab-Runner advanced config: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-global-section
- Find CPU roes on linux: [How to obtain the number of CPUs/cores in Linux from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481005/how-to-obtain-the-number-of-cpus-cores-in-linux-from-the-command-line)

Comment: There's no direct correlation between the number of cores and the the value of `concurrent`, best I can tell.  Each runner has access to all of the cpu cores granted to it via the host OS (modulated by `cpuset_cpus` if supplied).

Comment: @ChrisCleeland agreed to that, it seems like an arbitrary way of determining how much concurrency to handle. on gitlab's doc site for runner, it mentions memory consumption being the bottleneck. imo, i would set concurrency extremely high and autoscale and balance load based on mem consumption. however, ymmv, if you have jobs that are cpu intense, you're going to have to cater to that