# hardware thread numbers

Tags: macos, cpu, cpu-architecture

I'm trying to get information about my cpu in mac, I want to know numbers of hardware threads that exist on each core, and also the number of total physical and virtual core in my system. please tell me how can I gather these information in my laptop.

Comment: In which language or from the command line?

Comment: Are you sure you just don't want the total number of cores? If so you can use `sysctl` which is a system call.  The following question shows how to use the command line version, which will relate to how you can use the system call: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715580/how-to-discover-number-of-cores-on-mac-os-x

Comment: if number of hardware threads in a system are equal to sum numbers of physical and virtual cores, I need the number of cores. but I'm not sure they are the same, are they?

Comment: Old question, but the number of hardware threads possible is basically the number of logical cores `sysctl hw.logicalcpu` which would be a combination of the number of physical cores(cpus) * number of threads can run on the cpu (aka hyperthreading)