# Maximum number of workers in a parallel loop (local cluster) with Matlab R2014a?

Tags: matlab

I have a Macbook Pro Intel Core I7; which is the maximum number of workers in a parallel loop (local cluster) with Matlab R2014a?

Comment: That depends on your specific configuration, cf. http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/sldo/ug/how-to-use-parallel-computing-gui_bs2zam4-1.html

Comment: How can I see the specific configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Matlab R2014a you can have more than 12 local workers, however before creating too many workers you should see how many cores you have on your cpu. This information can be obtained as explained at https://stackoverflow.com/a/1715612/3676517.