# How to run a C++ program only on one CPU?

Tags: c++, process, cpu, multitasking

I've been reading around about how to check how many CPUs or cores my machine has (MacBook OS X, Sierra, v. 10.12, 2GHz Intel Core i7), but there are many different answers, for example here:

> [How to discover number of *logical* cores on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715580/how-to-discover-number-of-logical-cores-on-mac-os-x)

what I would need though is to make sure that my C++ program runs just 1 one CPU (and, if possible, only on one core, i.e., without scheduling, i.e., my program should have a dedicated core to run on => I'm not sure how my Mac OS X architecture is actually organised).

I am not sure if this should be done at implementation, compilation or execution level. I've seen people talking about `taskset` for Ubuntu, but I'm not sure if that's the right tool for me (maybe it does not even exist for Mac OS X).

*Note: if you feel this question should be asked in another Stack Exchange's website, just tell me, and I will move it to there. Actually I would like that my solution is cross-platform, so maybe this is not the best place to ask this question.*

Comment: This looks like an XY problem http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem  What is your use-case for wanting to restrict the OS scheduler?

Comment: @RichardCritten Environment constraints. My program could run a low-performant devices with only one CPU or core...

Comment: If you have only 1 CPU or core then you don't have a scheduler problem as your program only has one place to run.

Comment: @RichardCritten I know, but I would like to test my program on my Mac OS X simulating those low performant devices.

Comment: You say you have a MacBook with a 2 GHz Intel Core i7 CPU and Apple has yet to use a Core i7 CPU in a MacBook, although in a MacBook Air and MacBook Pro they have. So which model Apple computer do you actually have? They've used a Core m7 in a MacBook.

Comment: @user3439894 Sorry, I forgot to mention it: I've a macbook pro.

Comment: THis could be of interest: http://superuser.com/q/149312/655366

Comment: Are you asking how to make the program run on the same core or how to run using a program using just one thread?

Comment: @DavidAnderson I didn't mention threads. Of course I am aware of multi-threading and my application is a single-threaded application (with just one main).

Comment: Why do you need to do this? I can not image why you would care if a program ran on one core then later ran on a different core. Also, often a physical processor (core) can have logical processors (for hyper-threading). You do not address this in your question. A Simple answer would be to run the program in a virtual machine with just one processor.

Answer (score 6):

Processes are scheduled, the idea of a non-scheduled process is an oxymoron.

That said, restricting yourself to one CPU is pretty much the default in C++. `main` starts on one thread, and unless you create additional threads that's all you get.

You mention that you want a "dedicated" core. There's the idea of pinning a thread to a core, which sort of achieves that, but you can figure out what happens if two programs pin themselves to the same core. Another core might be fully unused while the two programs share that pinned core. This is more of a feature for supercomputers, where cores do not have uniform access to memory, and you should match CPU core and memory allocations.

Comment: But there may be a way to prevent two programs to pin themselves to the same core, I guess. Any specific suggestion on how to achieve it?

Comment: @nbro: You're suggesting that the OS vendor came up with an idea to make a bad idea slightly less bad. Why would they bother?

Comment: @nbro the other way round: what would justify to dedicate a full core to your program ?  Does it really need it ?  What guarantees would it offer that the precious CPU power is not wasted ?